# I am having a hard time rewriting my URL in htaccess to be more SEO friendly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/artwork/?$ painting.php?painting=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I am trying to make the URL instead to look like `example.com/artwork/paintingURL` and I am getting to this page from `<a href = "painting?painting=<?=$paintingURL?>">`. I've searched here and of the solutions I've gotten, none of the answers seem to work for me.

Update: After using RavinderSingh13's solution below, I am now getting 404 page not found error on the redirected url. On `painting.php` :

```php
<?php    
 if(isset($_GET['painting'])) {
 include('include/conn.php');    
 $paintingURL = $_GET['painting'];    
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `paintings` WHERE `painting_URL` = '$paintingURL'";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
 global $paintingName;
 global $paintingDesc;
 global $paintingImg;
 global $pageTitle;
    
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     
     $paintingName = $row['painting_Name'];
     $pageTitle = "Site Name - ".$paintingName;
     $paintingDesc = $row['size_description'];
     $paintingImg = $row['image_ID'];
  }    
} ?>
```

jsfiddle for how links are served: https://jsfiddle.net/h65u9fc3/

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for sharing your code. Could you please do mention(More clearly) which sample URL you are hitting in browser OR which sample URL will take request and what URL it should become in browser after redirect? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Sure - with this htaccess rewrite rule that I have, my browser is displaying `localhost/project-name/painting?painting=painting_name` in the URL and not `localhost/project-name/artwork/painting_name` .

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following .htaccess rules file.

***Please make sure to:***

- Keep your .htaccess rules file along with your project-name folder.
- Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /project-name/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(project-name)/painting\?painting=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/artwork/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(project-name/artwork/)([^/]*)/?$ project-name/painting.php?painting=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the message. The redirection is now working correctly, however on the redirected page, I am getting a 404 error that the requested page is not found. What would I have to do to fix this? I will update my original post with the php code and new error, in addition to marking your solution as it was the solution to my original question.

Comment: @wr87zl, ok cool. Lets fix the other thing now. So inside `painting` folder from what file you want to serve this redirected url in backend?

Comment: The file I want to serve is `painting.php` which is in the root directory of the project folder

Comment: @wr87zl, ok great, Good to know. I have edited my rules now. Please do check with new rules once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately that still results in a 404. I made sure to clear the cache and everything.

Comment: @wr87zl, so path for .php file is `project-name/painting.php`only and your htaccess is present along side with `project-name` folder only? Please confirm once.

Comment: The path for the php file, `painting.php` is in the root directory of the project folder. The project folder is named `project-name` and the .htaccess file is present in this same root directory. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: @wr87zl, ok could you please post 3 of their actual paths in here comments to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by actual paths. The page `painting.php` is supposed to be populated with data from my database, where it gets the last part of the url and uses that for data. hard entering a painting url (for example painting?painting=cat takes me to a 404 page on the url /artwork/cat

Comment: @wr87zl, path means like: `/singh/bla_bla/singh/test/painting.php` OR `/singh/bla_bla/singh/test/.htacess` etc etc like this

Comment: ok in that case `/project-name/painting.php``/project-name/.htaccess` `/project-name/gallery.php` `/project-name/animals.php` . These files are all in the root directory. `gallery.php` and `animals.php` in this example handles all the links to `painting.php?painting=` I updated original post with a jsfiddle for how the links are handled.

Comment: @wr87zl, please try my updated rules once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @wr87zl, make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: I have tried your updated code, including clearing my browser cache, trying different browsers, and I still get a 404 page on the redirected `project-name/artwork/painting_name`

Comment: @wr87zl, can you please try keeping your .htacces file along side with `project-name` folder(NOT inside it alongside with it), and then remove `RewriteBase /project-name/` line from my code and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @wr87zl, Could you please do let me know if changed code has worked for you? Cheers.